# Why does ^ interfere with [NC] in .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

This is the `.htaccess` file that I'm using for testing purposes. This is the entire file.

```
RewriteEngine On

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} asdf [NC]
    RewriteRule .* https://www.example.com/test/note.txt [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

`[NC]` (no case) works like a champ. `asdf`, `ASDF`, `AsDf` all trigger the rewrite rule. But if I include the `^` sign `[NC]` stops working. For example,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^asdf [NC]
```

With the `^` sign present only `asdf` triggers the rewrite. `ASDF` throws a 404.  I might be missing something but it appears that for some reason `^` interferes with `[NC]`. Why is this?

Comment: "With the `^` sign present only `asdf` triggers the rewrite. `ASDF` throws a 404." - that is not possible with the code you have posted - it sounds like a caching issue.

Answer (score 1):

`^` is a zero-width-assertion in regex, that is used to assert start of string. It is not interfering with `NC` flag here. Issue is that `REQUEST_URI` variable starts with a leading slash i.e. `/`, so you can use this rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/asdf [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/test/note.txt [R=302,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks anubhava but I changed that line to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/asdf [NC]` and it still threw a 404 when I tried ASDF in the address bar of my browser.

Comment: What is exact URL you enter in your browser and also make sure you clear browser cache